# Removal of BizTalk MBV spurious warning about running in VMware Virtual Platform

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010, mbv, bhm

Is there anyway to remove the spurious warning from the MBV / BizTalk Health Monitor, where it flags a non-critical warning about running on VMware ...

> Running in VMware Virtual Platform (Supported on ESX >=3.5) !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable rules in MBV or BHM (BHM and MBV share the same engine)

This is the tip to find the corresponding rule :

- open the HTML warnings report (in BHM, right click on the warning node and select the option to open in the browser)
- in the right side of the the warning entry in the HTML path you should see a rule id
- you need then to use MBV UI to find the query and the rule which produced the warning:
- in MBV GUI, if you select a specific query in the list of queries, you will see the list of its rules with their ID in the tab "Query Rules" below the queries list.
- once you found the corresponding rule matching the rule ID you can uncheck it in MBV GUI and exit the tool to save this change in the current profile.
- next time you will open MBV and use the updated profile to analyse the group, the rule will be disabled and so the warning.
- in BHM the button "Rules" in the tab "Information Level" will show all the rules corresponding to the level of queries you selected and you can then uncheck the rule(s) you want.

FYI the query for VMware is "OS Role Info" in the category "Server Details"
you will see the rule producing the warning for VMware and you can uncheck it.

In BHM v.Next we will add a button to display the rule id in front of each rule and in front of each warning visible in the Warnings MMC view (like for the HTML view)

Hope my explanations are enough clear

JP
MBV/BHM Team

Comment: JP, thanks for that. The BHM rules was "Runing [sic] in VMWARE", and as you said, OS Role Info, Servers Details

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to suppress a single specific rule.

The best you can get is to disable it's query object.  Queries\Server Details\OS Role Info (I think, sorry I don't have an unsupported platform right now :).